# Постраничный вывод и навигация

Tags: php, mysql

Фильтрую количество выводимых строк так:

```
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
if ( $num_rows==0 ) 
{
?> <script>
alert ('По Вашему запросу ничего не найдено')
document.location='/tt.php'
</script> <? 
}
```

Вместе с тем есть навигация, ссылки выводятся так:

```
<?php
if($page > 1) {
    echo '<a href="biblioteka.php?page='.($page-1).(isset($_REQUEST['radioselector'], $_REQUEST['poisk']) ? ('&radioselector='. $_REQUEST['radioselector'] . '&poisk=' . $_REQUEST['poisk']): null).'">[предыдущая]</a>';
}
echo '<a href="biblioteka.php?page='.($page+1).(isset($_REQUEST['radioselector'], $_REQUEST['poisk']) ? ('&radioselector='. $_REQUEST['radioselector'] . '&poisk=' . $_REQUEST['poisk']): null).'">[следующая]</a>';
?>
```

Получается так, что запрос выводит на каждой странице по 10 строк. Если их 10 или меньше, то навигация всё равно отображается и при нажатии на ссылку "следующая" выводится сообщение "По Вашему запросу ничего не найдено". Как сделать так, чтобы навигация не выводилась,  если запрос вернул 10 или менее строк.

Comment: поместить навигацию в блок else?

Comment: Хм, с каким условием?

Comment: с условием if ( $num_rows==0 )

Comment: if ($num_rows>=10)
{
 if($page > 1) {
    echo '<a href="biblioteka.php?page='.($page-1).(isset($_REQUEST['radioselector'], $_REQUEST['poisk']) ? ('&radioselector='. $_REQUEST['radioselector'] . '&poisk=' . $_REQUEST['poisk']): null).'">[предыдущая]</a>';
}
echo '<a href="biblioteka.php?page='.($page+1).(isset($_REQUEST['radioselector'], $_REQUEST['poisk']) ? ('&radioselector='. $_REQUEST['radioselector'] . '&poisk=' . $_REQUEST['poisk']): null).'">[следующая]</a>';
}
работает такой вариант, но на последней странице поиска он не показывает навигацию